# Linker error: "bad address <value> for zero page symbol <name>"!

Tags: memory-management, linker, linker-errors, microcontroller

I'm trying to make `COSMIC` compiler allocate a struct at a specific address in the memory (`0x5420`). I added the following lines in my C code (where `CAN_TypeDef` is a `typedef struct`):

```
#pragma section [mycan]
CAN_TypeDef CAN;
#pragma section []
```

In the IDE (`STVD`), I created a new section named `Can` inside which I created a new section named `.mycan`.

[image: Creating a new segment and section]

When I build the code in `STVD`, a linker error appears saying:

```
#error clnk Debug\can.lkf:1 bad address (0x5420) for zero page symbol _CAN
```

In the above picture, it is clear that `Can` and `Zero Page` are two different segments. What can be the cause of this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: For which type of microcontroller?

Comment: It's an Stm8s one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the STM8, but I think I found it. In the [STVD documentation](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/e9/d3/c3/4b/2c/0b/46/f2/CD00004556.pdf/files/CD00004556.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00004556.pdf) I read:

> **Global variables**
>
> When the category is set to  General , you can use
>   the  Global Variables list box to specify  the default location of
>   global variables:
>
> - In Zero Page:  This is the default option.
> - In Data:  Specifies to place global variables in the first 64Kbytes of
>     memory.

So the compiler assumes all global data sitting in the zero page and the addresses are just **eight bit** wide. Only the linker sees that the section .mycan is not in the zero page and you get an error. I would try `@near CAN_TypeDef CAN;` or simply `extern CAN_TypeDef CAN @5420;` without creating your own section.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I've already tried this solution and it gives me another error `space attribute conflict`. The direct locating method (i.e., `@5420`) works fine but it doesn't work with Tessy (unit testing tool) for some reason.

Comment: We found that the cause of the second error (`space attribute conflict`) is solved by changing (mods0 to modsl0) in the linker options. I don't really understand what it is but it is explained in page 39 in COSMIC manual. I'll try to understand it more. Thanks